# In Edge, calling typeof on a super method returns 'function' even though that method is not present in the parent class

Tags: javascript, class, microsoft-edge, super

I noticed this on Edge recently (non-chromium versions), and wondered if anyone could shed any light on the matter.

Here is an example to illustrate ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/royranger/n0pyLw97/)):

```
class Parent {}

class Child extends Parent {
    b() {}

    test() {
        console.log('super.a -->', super.a);
        console.log('typeof super.a -->', typeof super.a);

        console.log('super.b -->', super.b);
        console.log('typeof super.b -->', typeof super.b);
    }
}

const child = new Child();

child.test();
```

In other browsers, all four values that are logged are `undefined` as expected. However, in Edge 18, the final value `typeof super.b` is `function` instead. It seems as though, even though it correctly gives `super.b` as `undefined`, when it checks `typeof super.b`, it is checking `b` from the current class and not from the parent.

Any explanations as to what is happening here?

Comment: They must be defaulting to `this`, when super method is undefined. I would use constructors instead anyways. It's easier to use private variables that way.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @StackSlave. Other than that I did not get any information in the documentation about why Edge legacy browser return function. I suggest you try to use the new MS Edge Chromium browser. It does not have this issue.